# Robotframework: how to create json in keywords with specifying arguments in testcase

Tags: robotframework

I use robot framework at following environment.

- Python 2.7.6
- robotframework 2.8.7
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

I want to create json from keyvalue to Post request.
I tried following pattern and 
Test Create Json1 work correctly, but Test Create Json2 does not.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
Library    json

*** Variables ***
${NAME}    XXXX
${ID}    YYYY

*** Test Cases ***
Test Create Json1
    ${req_dict}    Create Dictionary    name=${NAME}    id=${ID}
    ${req_json}    Json.Dumps    ${req_dict}
    Log To Console    *** Test Create Json1 Result ***
    Log To Console    ${req_json}

Test Create Json2
    ${resp}    Prepare Json Keyword    name=${NAME}    id=${ID}
    Log To Console    *** Test Create Json2 Result ***
    Log To Console    ${resp}

*** Keywords ***
Prepare Json Keyword
    [Arguments]    @{args}
    ${req_dict}    Create Dictionary    @{args}
    ${req_json}    Json.Dumps    ${req_dict}
    [Return]    ${req_json}
```

OutPut

```
Test Create Json1
{"name": "XXXX", "id": "YYYY"}

Test Create Json2
{"name=XXXX": "id=YYYY"}
```

I want to create json in Keyword, how can I change Test Create Json2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root issue is in dictionary creation. In test 1 you create dictionary properly. It requires name=parameter pairs.

In test 2 you are passing "NAME=XXXX" "ID=YYYY" strings. This creates a dictionary with key "NAME=XXXX" and value "ID=YYYY".

You need to split strings and set them to dictionary like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
Library    json
Library    String

*** Variables ***
${NAME}    XXXX
${ID}    YYYY

*** Test Cases ***
Test Create Json1
    ${req_dict}    Create Dictionary    name=${NAME}    id=${ID}
    ${req_json}    Json.Dumps    ${req_dict}
    Log To Console    *** Test Create Json1 Result ***
    Log To Console    ${req_json}

Test Create Json2
    ${resp}    Prepare Json Keyword    name=${NAME}    id=${ID}
    Log To Console    *** Test Create Json2 Result ***
    Log To Console    ${resp}

*** Keywords ***
Prepare Json Keyword
    [Arguments]    @{args}
    ${req_dict}    Create Dictionary
    :FOR     ${pair}    IN     @{args}
    \     ${key}    ${value}=     Split String    ${pair}    =
    \     Set To Dictionary    ${req_dict}    ${key}=${value}
    ${req_json}    Json.Dumps    ${req_dict}
    [Return]    ${req_json}
```

Comment: I understand  passed @{args} are interpreted as "strings",so I should remake dictionary in keywords. Your sample works correctly. Thank you !